# Using ggplot in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
publishers
          Publisher       Date        Number    Number2
            A         2015-08-01   2602777.0     3.4
            B         2015-08-01    255545.0     5
            C         2015-08-01      4951.0     6 
            A         2015-08-02    417117.1     7
            B         2015-08-02    256715.0     8
            C         2015-08-02       118.0     9
```

I want to create a graph in shiny using ggplot. So here is what I did so far and there is an error:

```
# ui.R
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Title"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            helpText("Text"),
            selectInput("var", 
                label = "Choose a variable to display",
                choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
                selected = "A"),

            mainPanel(plotOutput("map"))
        )
    )
))

# server.R
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
publishers <- read.csv("data/syndicationshiny.csv")
source("helpers.R")
head(publishers)
publishers$Date<-as.Date(publishers$Date,'%m/%d/%Y')


shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    output$map <- renderPlot({
      data <- switch(input$var, 
            "A" = publishers[ which(publishers$Publisher=='A'),],
            "B" = publishers[which(publishers$Publisher=='B'),],
            "C" = publishers[ which(publishers$Publisher=='C'),]),
      color <- switch(input$var, 
                      "A" = "darkgreen",
                      "B" = "black",
                      "C" = "darkorange")

      legend <- switch(input$var, 
                       "A" = "A",
                       "B" = "B",
                       "C" = "C"),

      ggplot(var,aes(x=Date,y=Number) 
                  color = color, 
                  legend.title = legend)+geom_line()
    })
  }
)
```

I am getting an error that reads:
Error in sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(helpText("Text"),  : 
  argument "mainPanel" is missing, with no default

I think my issue is in ggplot.

If anyone has any ideas on what is wrong with this it would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me like a parenthesis problem. It's a little hard to tell with your indentation, but it looks to me like your `mainPanel()` is inside `sidebarPanel()`, when it should be after the end paren of `sidebarPanel()` but still inside `sidebarLayout()`.

Comment: I've redone your `ui.R` indentation so that the nesting is more clear. It shows that my first comment is correct, you need to move `mainPanel()` outside of `sidebarPanel()`. I'm voting to close as typo.

Comment: @Gregor I fixed the parenthesis and comma problems I'm pretty sure but now the error is saying: "Error : ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class function"

Comment: Okay, so that's a completely different problem, which sounds like a completely new question.

Comment: Though, at a glance, it looks like `var` is a character, either A, B or C, and you're passing `var` to `ggplot()` as the data argument. Perhaps you should give it a data frame instead (your `data` object is a data frame. Some people would say since `data` is also a function in base R you should call it something else).

Comment: @Gregor I am very new to this and tell me if I'm wrong. "var" is calling A, B, or C but it is producing a dataframe when doing this from the: publishers[which(publishers$Publisher=='A'),]

Comment: `var` isn't calling anything, `var` is just a value. It will be A, B or C. Since it's reactive, it looks like you define `data` to depend on `var`, when a use changes `var`, `data` will also change. You call the data frame `data`, not `var`, you can see this where you have `data <- ...`. Now, `ggplot()` likes to plot data frames. When you look at `?ggplot`, the first argument is data, which needs to be a data frame. So use `ggplot(data, ...)` rather than `ggplot(var, ...)`.

Comment: @Gregor when I do that it states: "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Date' not found"